# Realloc doesn't seem to enlarge array

Tags: c, realloc

so I have to write something like garbage collector for school project in C. I am stuck at problem with dynamic memory allocation. My function growActivePtrs() should enlarge global array of structs by one, but it does not seem to be working. I have read a ton on materials on dynamic allocation and tried many things, but I just cant find the mistake.

```
typedef struct activePtr
{
    // pointer to actively used memory
    void *memPointer;
    // number of times this memory is referenced
    int timesUsed;
} activePtr;


activePtr **activePointers;
size_t *ptrCount = 0;


bool growActivePtrs()
{
    const size_t totalSize = *ptrCount + 1;
    activePtr *temp = (activePtr *)realloc(*activePointers, (totalSize * sizeof(activePtr)));

    if (temp == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    *activePointers = temp;
    *ptrCount += 1;
    activePointers[*ptrCount - 1]->timesUsed = 0;
    activePointers[*ptrCount - 1]->memPointer = NULL;
    return true;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your shown code above is not an [MCVE]. So compile your entire program with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Improve your code to get no warnings. [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> size_t *ptrCount = 0;
> ```

This defines `ptrCount` as a pointer to `size_t`, initialised to a null pointer. Unless you assign it the location of some actual `size_t` object (and it looks like you haven't), any attempt to access `*ptrCount` is doomed to fail.

There is no reason why this should be a pointer. You can just store a `size_t` directly.

As @user3121023 rightly points out in a comment, the same applies to your `activePointers` variable.